# jQuery dropdown plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugin

I'm looking for OOP tips or advice.

```
    ;(function ( $, window, document, undefined ) {

  if ( typeof Object.create !== 'function' ) {
    Object.create = function (o) {
        function F() {}
        F.prototype = o;
        return new F();
    };
  }

  if (!Function.prototype.bind) { // check if native implementation available
    Function.prototype.bind = function(){ 
      var fn = this, args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments),
          object = args.shift(); 
      return function(){ 
        return fn.apply(object, 
          args.concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments))); 
      }; 
    };
  }

  $.component = function( name, object ) {
    $.fn[name] = function( options ) {
      return this.each(function() {
        if ( !$.data( this, name ) ) {
          $.data( this, name, Object.create(object).init( 
            $.extend(true, {}, $.fn[name].opts, options), this ) 
          );
        }
      });
    };
  };

})( jQuery, window , document );

(function ( $, window, document, undefined ) {

  var dropdown = {
    opts: {},
    init: function( options, el ) {
      this.$el = $(el).on('click.dropdown', 
        (function(evt){
          this.toggle(evt);
        }).bind(this)
      );
      this.opts = $.extend(true, this.opts, options);
      this.isShowing = false;
      return this;
    },
    show: function (evt) {
      if(evt) evt.preventDefault(); evt.stopPropagation();
      $(this.opts.header).addClass('show-mobile-nav');
      this.isShowing = true;
      this.bindClose();
    },
    hide: function (evt) {
      if(evt) evt.preventDefault();
      $(this.opts.header).removeClass('show-mobile-nav');
      this.isShowing = false;
      return this;
    },
    bindClose: function () {
      $('html').on('click.dropdown',
        (function(evt){
          var $targ = $(event.target || window.event.srcElement),
          targetIsNotDropdown = !$targ.is(this.opts.menu),
          targetsNotAChildOfDropdown = $(this.opts.menu).has( $targ ).length == 0;
          if( targetIsNotDropdown && targetsNotAChildOfDropdown) {
            $('html').off('.dropdown');
            this.hide();
          }
        }).bind(this)
      );
      return this;
    },
    toggle: function (evt) {
      if(evt) evt.preventDefault();
      if ( !this.isShowing ) {
        this.show(evt);
      } else {
        this.hide(evt);
      }
    }
  };

  $.component('dropdown',dropdown);

})( jQuery, window , document );
```

Answer (score 2):

From a once over:

- Your code is not consistently indented, especially the first dozen lines need some TLC
- `$.component = function( name, object ) {` needs commenting, it is not clear what this is trying to achieve.
- `evt` is an unfortunate parameter name, I would go for the classic `e` or the readable `event`
- `$targ` is needlessly short, just use `$target`
- You could probably use helper functions for `if(evt) evt.preventDefault();` and `if(evt) evt.preventDefault(); evt.stopPropagation();`
- Note that `if(evt) evt.preventDefault(); evt.stopPropagation();` is exactly the kind of bug that makes people enforce `{}` around `if` blocks!
- `toggle()` could use a ternary condition with `!this.isShowing`
- `'show-mobile-nav'` should probably not be hardcoded since you use it more than once, instead you should use a properly named variable

All in all, some pretty cool code.